# Backup/Restore an azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, backup, virtual-machine, snapshot

I would like to know the fastest way to backup and then restore an azure VM. Something like taking a snapshot and then reversing to it later (like with a traditional virtual machine).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there isn't any out of the box method at the moment. In the end I used powershell scripts to get the most automatization of the process.

Answer (score 1):

I did by using blob. It is very efficient and creates a .vhd files as a backup.
just go to Azure portal->Storage-> open ur vhd -> containers-> download the vhd file.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to protect both ARM VMs with Azure Backup is now in public preview. You can find more information at  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/

You can find the steps to backup classic VMs in the same area, but that feature has been available for while.